# Js doesnt work although no errors is present

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a jsfiddle where the range-sliders worked fine until sometime ago.

dont know what went wrong, and can't find the error.

Basically its 6 range-slider which can should result in a total result based on where you position the sliders.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#slider1").slider({
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            slide: function(event, ui) {
                update();
            }
        });

        $("#slider2").slider({
            min: 0,
            max: 250,
            slide: function(event, ui) {
                update();
            }
        });

        $("#slider3").slider({
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            slide: function(event, ui) {
                update();
            }
        });

        $("#slider4").slider({
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            slide: function(event, ui) {
                update();
            }
        });

        $("#slider5").slider({
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            slide: function(event, ui) {
                update();
            }
        });

        $("#slider6").slider({
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            slide: function(event, ui) {
                update();
            }
        });

        update(); };
    }),

    function update() {
         $("#amount").val($amount1);
         $("#amount2").val($amount2);
         $("#amount3").val($amount3);
         $("#amount4").val($amount4);
         $("#amount5").val($amount5);
         $("#amount6").val($amount6);
         $("#amount7").val($amount7);
         $("#gbamount").val($gbamount);
         $("#gbamount2").val($gbamount2);
         $("#gbamount3").val($gbamount3);
         $("#gbamount4").val($gbamount4);
         $("#gbamount5").val($gbamount5);
         $("#gbamount6").val($gbamount6);

    $amount1 = $("#slider1").slider("values", 0);
    $amount2 = $("#slider2").slider("values", 0);
    $amount3 = $("#slider3").slider("values", 0);
    $amount4 = $("#slider4").slider("values", 0);
    $amount5 = $("#slider5").slider("values", 0);
    $amount6 = $("#slider6").slider("values", 0);
    $gbamount = ($amount1 * 3 / 1024).toFixed(2);
    $gbamount2 = ($amount2 * 30 / 10240).toFixed(2);
    $gbamount3 = ($amount3 * (1.43333333 * 30) / 1024).toFixed(2);
    $gbamount4 = ($amount4 * (10 * 60) / 8 / 1024).toFixed(2);
    $gbamount5 = ($amount5 * (30 * 60) / 8 / 1024).toFixed(2);
    $gbamount6 = ($amount6 * (30 * 0.1666666667) / 1024).toFixed(2);
    $amount7 = ($gbamount + $gbamount2 + $gbamount3 + $gbamount4 + $gbamount5 + $gbamount6).toFixed(2);

    };
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jossiossi/b7tqtwnL/2/

Comment: It seems to be you missed adding jQuery slider plugin. ```Uncaught TypeError: $(...).slider is not a function``` was printed in my console output.

Comment: You forgot `var` declarations.

Comment: You are absolutely right! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi please make sure to include the library

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

check here

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Slider - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#slider" ).slider();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="slider"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/b7tqtwnL/4/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
function update() {

$amount1 = $("#slider1").slider("values", 0);
$amount2 = $("#slider2").slider("values", 0);
$amount3 = $("#slider3").slider("values", 0);
$amount4 = $("#slider4").slider("values", 0);
$amount5 = $("#slider5").slider("values", 0);
$amount6 = $("#slider6").slider("values", 0);
$gbamount = ($amount1 * 3 / 1024).toFixed(2);
$gbamount2 = ($amount2 * 30 / 10240).toFixed(2);
$gbamount3 = ($amount3 * (1.43333333 * 30) / 1024).toFixed(2);
$gbamount4 = ($amount4 * (10 * 60) / 8 / 1024).toFixed(2);
$gbamount5 = ($amount5 * (30 * 60) / 8 / 1024).toFixed(2);
$gbamount6 = ($amount6 * (30 * 0.1666666667) / 1024).toFixed(2);
console.log($gbamount + $gbamount2 + $gbamount3 + $gbamount4 + $gbamount5 + $gbamount6)
$amount7 = (Number($gbamount) + Number($gbamount2)+ Number($gbamount3) + Number($gbamount4) + Number($gbamount5) + Number($gbamount6)).toFixed(2);
     $("#amount").val($amount1);
     $("#amount2").val($amount2);
     $("#amount3").val($amount3);
     $("#amount4").val($amount4);
     $("#amount5").val($amount5);
     $("#amount6").val($amount6);
     $("#amount7").val($amount7);
     $("#gbamount").val($gbamount);
     $("#gbamount2").val($gbamount2);
     $("#gbamount3").val($gbamount3);
     $("#gbamount4").val($gbamount4);
     $("#gbamount5").val($gbamount5);
     $("#gbamount6").val($gbamount6);


};
    $("#slider1").slider({
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            update();
        }
    });

    $("#slider2").slider({
        min: 0,
        max: 250,
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            update();
        }
    });

    $("#slider3").slider({
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            update();
        }
    });

    $("#slider4").slider({
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            update();
        }
    });

    $("#slider5").slider({
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            update();
        }
    });

    $("#slider6").slider({
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            update();
        }
    });

    //update(); };
})
```